# can't get entrez to return mesh terms using biopython

Tags: python, biopython, pubmed

quick question -- first time using biopython and I'm just trying to jury-rig something real quick based on tutorials.

I can't seem to get `Entrez.efetch()` to return mesh terms for a given article, and the only method appears to be what I'm doing, namely:

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmids, rettype="medline", retmode="xml")
records = Entrez.read(handle)
```

where pmids is a list of *pubmed IDs*

this returns the following: http://pastie.org/5459700

I've tried tweaking the rettype and retmode parameters per http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/ with no luck. anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: What's the question exactly ? Your output is a _python dict_...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is best asked on the Biopython mailing list or perhaps the http://www.biostars.org/ . It's much more likely there to find people with Entrez experience.

The problem is that the record with [PMID 23165874](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23165874) doesn't have any MeSH terms. Compare the [raw XML of that record](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=23165874&retmode=xml) to [one which has MeSH terms](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=12654674&retmode=xml). The latter has a section starting:

```
<MeshHeadingList>
  <MeshHeading>
    <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">ADP Ribose Transferases</DescriptorName>
    <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y">genetics</QualifierName>
  </MeshHeading>
  <MeshHeading>
    <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Acinetobacter</DescriptorName>
    <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y">drug effects</QualifierName>
    <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y">genetics</QualifierName>
  </MeshHeading>
  ..
```

In other words, it's hard to get something which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! If you can believe it, I worked this out on my own just before reading your response. Silly error; appreciate your help!

Comment: One of the challenges with Entrez and Pubmed is that the PMID and record are created before the MeSH indexing is performed. So, while this record didn't have MeSH terms at the time of posting, it does now!

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
from Bio import Entrez # install with 'pip install biopython'
from Bio.Entrez import efetch, read
Entrez.email = "your@email.com" # register your email

def get_mesh(pmid):
    # call PubMed API
    handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=str(pmid), retmode='xml')
    xml_data = read(handle)[0]
    # skip articles without MeSH terms
    if u'MeshHeadingList' in xml_data['MedlineCitation']:
        for mesh in xml_data['MedlineCitation'][u'MeshHeadingList']:
            # grab the qualifier major/minor flag, if any
            major = 'N'
            qualifiers = mesh[u'QualifierName']
            if len(qualifiers) > 0:
                major = str(qualifiers[0].attributes.items()[0][1])
            # grab descriptor name
            descr = mesh[u'DescriptorName']
            name = descr.title()

            yield(name, major)

# example output
for name, major in get_mesh(128):
    print '{}, {}'.format(name, major)
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the code. I'm trying to get it run though it raises the error: `xml_data = read(handle)[0]
KeyError: 0` do you have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: sorry no, it's been too long. please post the fix if you find it